# Weird mouse behavior on right click

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I found recently that strange thing is happening when I right click on selected script or layer in a table of content. Some items of pop-up menu are faded:

[image]

If I repeat right click 3 or more times, they become available. Another option is keyboard shortcut Shift+F10, which is far from ideal. It happens on a long lists, e.g. over 15 layers in the table of content.

I am using ArcGIS 10.5.1 and I have a suspicion that this is yet another windows update, the latest I have is "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903", early September.

This is not happening in other applications, e.g. explorer. It seems specific to ArcGIS. It looks like a minor thing, but I found it very annoying.

Are you experiencing this behavior and hopefully know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you certain the toolbox (.tbx) file isn't locked by another application? Perhaps you have a slow-to-close ArcMap or ArcCatalog that is holding a file lock preventing changes, you should be able to check for these in task manager, details tab, sorted by Name (just because ArcMap and ArcCatalog are close to the beginning of an alphabetical sort) if there are more instances there than you have visible or expected windows it could mean you have a locking problem.

Comment: @Michael Stimson It is not the case, I've checked it. It also happening in ArcMap table of content, no chance of it being blocked.

Comment: Have you tried renaming Normal.mxd or renaming entire folder  ArcMap in: C:\Users\<users>\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.X\   or rename normal.mxt C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.X\ArcMap\Templates

Comment: @JuniorPythonNewbie  I tried you suggestion, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try renaming your `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Documents\ArcGIS` folder and let ArcMap creates a new one for you to see if this fixes your problem? This has fixed a totally different problem for me, but who knows...

Comment: @umbe1987 I am testing it. It's looking good so far. Perhaps post it as answer, I'll accept it, if it will still work tomorrow.

Comment: @FelixIP Glad it worked! Let me know if you have problems tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename your `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Documents\ArcGIS` folder and launch ArcMap to let it re-create it from scratch. In my case, it contains these folders/files:

[image]

If this works, either delete or keep the renamed folder: you won't need it anymore.

This has solved a totally different problem for me (in my case, I had the size of my MXDs being huge like hundreds of MB! After I tried this, the size returned normal).

Comment: the mxd size goiing  up could be caused by the geoprocessing history, check your setting to see if that's the case.....

Comment: I already checked that when I had that problem and unfortunately I could not fix it. really good point though, thanks.